# Angular Material: How to pass a predefined Components inside mat-stepper?

Tags: angular, dynamic, mat-stepper

I would like to pass pre defined (but the selector not used in template) components into mat stepper.
How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Can you add some code to show what you have tried?

Comment: I just theoretically interested in.